# Viewing binary files in vim displays gibberish

Tags: text-editing

When I open up a binary file in Vim, it displays a bunch of gibberish. One would expect it to display a bunch of 1s and 0s. Why is this?

Comment: One does not simply Vim into Binary.

Comment: If you are using UNIX you can use the `hd` or hexdump command to dump out the the file in HEX and printable characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question.

Text editors don't open files and show binary. They typically read files with ASCII or Unicode encoding.

Here's some examples of how ASCII encoding works:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Basically the way it works is, it reads the first number of bytes, and then interprets that collection of bits as a certain character, which is what you're seeing on your screen.

However, if you **want** to show binary (or hex) in Vim, you can, by doing something like this:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump